# Adding a dependency to Android project for jar

Tags: java, android, localytics

I'm attempting to integrate Localytics into my Android project. Their steps for integration include:

```
Add a dependency to your project for the jar.
```

How do I do that?

Comment: what IDE are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

using gradle :

```
repositories {
       flatDir {
           dirs 'libs'
       }
    }


    dependencies {
       compile name: 'gson-2.2.4'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your .jar file in your libs folder.

> PROJECT_NAME/app/libs/example.jar

2. Add the .jar file to your dependencies in the gradle file.

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile files('libs/example.jar')
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android studio, switch to "Project" view, locate the Jar(s) you want to add as dependency. Right click on the Jars and select "Add as Library".

PS: To open the "Project" view. Use the menu View > Tool Windows > Project

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the Localytics jar into your app/libs folder.
2. Right click on the Localytics.jar file and select "Add as Library" from the conntext menu
3. Finally make sure that you see the folling in app/build.gradle

   dependencies {
           compile files('libs/localytics.jar')
       }